# Why can I not save a sequence with lens effects as png with alpha in 3Ds MAX Vray?

Tags: 3dsmax

I have using Bloom/glare effect on my renders by vray lens effect.

Regardless of the fact that its speed is much lower than version 3.6

the glares effect not saving when the output is PNG.
and if I save it with JPG it have fewer glare than original render in VFB.

why it happen, where I missing?

is there only way to use 3Ds MAX 2018 with Vray 3.6 ?!!!